# Android View's .onMeasure side effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-measure

I'm having an issue where `.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)` somehow alters the view's state.

I've set up a view which listens to the `onClick` event and performs the `.measure`. Note that when I perform this directly in `onCreate`, it does not occur.

I expect that this code should only re-draw my `textView` with green color, not change any position.

**Simple view:**

[image]

**Same view after clicking it. Notice how the position is off:**

[image]

**Activity:**

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.foo)
        val tv = root.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.bar)
        tv.setOnClickListener {
            tv.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            tv.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.green))
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="io.flogging.activities.Main2Activity"
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2">
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="Please let me be in center"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: don't call tv.measure

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to be calling `measure()` in the first place. The system should take care of that for you. Just go ahead and delete that call.

If you've left something out of the question, and you absolutely **must** call `measure()`, then you need to make sure that you pass the correct parameters. [The documentation for `View.measure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure(int,%20int)) specifies that you must pass "measure specs", **not** `LayoutParams` constants. That is, instead of what you have, you would pass something that looked like this:

```
tv.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
           View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

Both `View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)` and `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` are of type `int`, which is why the compiler doesn't complain and the app doesn't crash. But you can't just pass any old `int` to this method.

Note, however, that the *explicit purpose* of this call is to change the layout of the view. So if you call measure, then you're going to change the view's layout, *because that is what it does*.

> Note that when I perform this directly in onCreate, it does not occur.

I don't know for sure, but I suspect that this is because your manual call to `measure()` in `onCreate()` comes *before* a system-intiated call to `measure()` during view layout, so your modified structure gets thrown out. When you do it in an `OnClickListener` instead, then your manual call comes second, and overrides the system-initiated call.

Comment: In my use case, this view is initially hidden and i'm using this measurement method to animate said view to the height of WRAP_CONTENT's size. Any tips there?